# I get UNAUTHENTICATED error when I call Method: purchases.subscriptions.get endpoint

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

When I try to call [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D) from my backend server to verify a purchase I receive :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

How can I authenticate from my **backend server** (so without any user interface)? Is there any way to create an **API key** somewhere and use it to authenticate?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  You need to be authorized with Oauth2 to  run this request.  Your missing the authorization header with a bearer token

Comment: @DaImTo I don't want to use Oauth2 but instead use an api key. seam it's possible but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: The method you are using requires Oauth2 in order to access private user data,  APIkeys are only for accessing public data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

States that authorization is required.

If you check the documentation for [Method: purchases.subscriptions.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get)

You will notices that it states that this method requires authorization with the following scope

[image]

Assuming this is an account you the developer control and you only want to access this single account you should look into using a service account for authorization. Documentation here [Using a service account](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_a_service_account)